# Extend View and add listeners to its children

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

Very simple question:

I am inflating a view:

```
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_location, null);

final EditText location_input           = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.location_input);
final View location_button_clear        = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.location_button_clear);
final Button current_location_dialog    = (Button) dialogView.findViewById ( R.id.current_location_dialog );
```

And I am later passing a lot of listeners to each child view e.g.

```
location_button_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  ...  } 
current_location_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ... }
location_input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  ...  }
```

That makes my code a spageti and I do not like it. For maintainability reasons I would like to create a new separate class having inside that file the listeners etc.

**Is it possible to extend dialogView as a view?** e.g.

```
public class DialogView extends View{
   // somehow here inflate the R.layout.dialog_location   
   // get the children and set the listeners 
}
```

or my only choice is to extend DialogView as a `Fragment` e.g.

```
public class DialogView extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_location, container, false);
    }

   // other stuff here
}
```

Update:

My main problem is how to inflate the `R.layout.dialog_location` if I extend the view

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly extend `View` for this, as your original shows `dialogView` as of type `View`. However, as you didn't specify how are you planning to organize it, I'm not sure how will this enhace your code readability.

In order to maintainability reasons I'd preferably suggest the following:

- If you're using the same `Listener` for several `View`s, define it separately and assign the same `Listener` to all the `View`s that will have the same behavior.
- If you're having really lots of `Listener`s, I'd create a separate class as a Singleton and define the whole implementation there. Afterwards, if you need to assign them to some of your `View`s, you'd call something like `mySingleton.getMyFooListener()` on `myView.setOnWhateverListener(...)`.

Comment: I just want to create an "enhanced view". It's not the listeners that matter much (used only once to answer your question), but I just want to make this view with some extra features (embedded children and their listeners) and not get involved with that code again. Check update

Comment: The best way would be inflating the `View` inside the class that has its layout. It's hard and even discouraged accessing a `View` from a class that doesn't have the layout that contains it. That's why I proposed separating just the "hard code" into a separate class, this way you'd have the layout implementation where it goes and the auxiliary code (Listeners and similar stuff) in a separate class where you can simply call `getMyListener()` to get it and not make your code confusing.